# Turn Select dropdown list not writeable

Tags: java, select, drop-down-menu, vaadin

I'm programming a GUI in Java using the Vaadin framework having a question about adjusting the behaviour of a drop down list.

What is the correct property action to make a drop down list of the type Select none-writeable. That is, when selected I don't want the "write-marker" to flash in the list expecting input but rather have the drop down list expand on such an action.

I've tried with `searchDropDown.setReadOnly(true);` but that turned off the drop down behaviour completely...

Anyone have any ideas...? =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [NativeSelect](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#NativeSelection) instead of [ComboBox](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#ComboBoxPlain)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm currently using a component of the type 'Select', so it's not a ComboBox. I'll give it a try with the type 'NativeSelect' once I can build the project again, having some back-end work being done on it at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, Select is in fact a ComboBox.

Comment: Now I've tried it, and you were correct! This stopped the input prompt behaviour the drop-down had earlier. Thanks!